# Creating a yes or no questionnaire in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario in which users complete a quiz. The rubricks are as follows:

- A series of questions with a radio button next to them with either yes or no
- Each question is either +1 or -1 given the answer of yes or no
- Each question falls into its own category (so the user will get a score per category)
- This data is collected and presented back to the user
- The questions from any category can be in a random order

My thought process is, have a users table in a database as well as a questions table and an answers table.

The question table would include an ID, the question itself, a category that it falls into.

The answer table would have the question id and the correct answer (in this case either yes or no).

When the page is loaded x amount of questions are grabbed from the database and put into a form.

The user completing the quiz will have a score for each section associated with them, perhaps in a score table.

This will be updated when the user submits the form.

Programmatically, would this work, or am I over inflating an issue?

Comment: With these dsorts of open ended questions would it be more beneficial if I wrote up the solution and then queried it?

Comment: Not sure of the background here but if you've been tasked with coming up with a system like this, you should consider looking to see if there are any open source solutions that can do it for you without you having to write it from scratch. For example, take a look at [Moodle](http://moodle.org/). Moodle is a full-featured e-learning package, so it does a lot more than you're asking for, but it certainly does include the ability to run a quiz that can be scored. It ticks all the boxes in your requirements. If you don't like Moodle, there are other e-learning packages as well that might suit you

Answer (score 0):

Possible.
It is possible and can be implemented.

You can do this by ensuring that you have an user table that store the unique primary ID for the user with this the number of categories can have different table or you can do that in a single table by giving each category a particular flag type with which all the question from a particular category can be easily distinguish . If the user is attempting questions you can store their answers in a separate table so that you can compare them with the actual answers so that you can show the result back to the user with their score.

**For random order generation.**
Store the questions with a particular unique ID and store them in a array and shuffle them using array shuffler in PHP and then show the question accordingly.